# Unable to receive UDP broadcast packets client side using python

Tags: python, sockets

I have been trying to send broadcast message for a long time but unable to receive it at all from the other side and no error at all. Server side it quickly sends packet and client keeps listening but never prints. Please answer me if someone really did this. I am using two virtual machines of same linux ubuntu. One for server and other for client.

```
#client

from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("192.168.1.255",12345))
print s.recvfrom(4096)[0]

#server

from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.sendto("hi i am server!", ("<broadcast>", 12345))
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it myself.

Server side:

```
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.sendto("hi i am server!", ("192.168.1.255", 12345))
```

Client side:

```
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("192.168.1.255",12345))
print s.recvfrom(4096)[0]
```

Instead of using "<broadcast>" as an address we should use the same subnet address